# how do i call both constructor initializers, base() and this()?

Tags: c#, constructor

This is easy to work around, but I just curious if I could be using a language feature or possibly the fact that the language disallows it means I'm making a logical error in class design.

I'm doing a self review of my code to help "harden" it for re-use and I just came accross:

```
public partial class TrackTyped : Component
{
    IContainer components = null;

    public TrackTyped()
        : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public TrackTyped(IContainer container)
        : base()
    {
        container.Add(this);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

What I usually do when I see the same line of code in two constructors is make one call the other with "this()" but I can't seem to do it.

If I read the spec right (I just started trying to read the spec so I may not be right):

```
10.11 Instance Constructors
   constructor-declarator:
      identifier   (   formal-parameter-listopt   )   constructor-initializeropt
   constructor-initializer:
      :   base   (   argument-listopt   )
      :   this   (   argument-listopt   )
```

It's saying I can only have one of those.

QUESTION: is 10.11 implying that there's no reason to need to call both or is it simply implying that the language only supports calling  one?

Comment: Thanks EVERYone for the (obvious now, not so obvious to me a min ago) answer :)

Comment: no, I just didn't think of the answer myself for some reason - I don't think container.Add(this) needs to happen before InitializeComponent() - and if it did I'd probably ask myself if that was a sign of wierd design.

Comment: in the example, "new TrackedType()" is executed first, then .Add().  Personally, I find it clearer that way.  Keep it in mind for later perhaps.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no need to call both, because `this` redirects to another constructor that will call `base`.

Answer (score 14):

You don't and you can't. You can forward the constructor call to another constructor of the same class by `:this(...)`. The last constructor in that chain will have to initialize the base either implicitly or explicitly by `:base(...)`

Suppose class A has two constructors. One initializes the base with `:base(2)`, the other with `:base(3)`. If the first constructor was allowed to also specify `:this (/*call the other ctor*/)` how should the base have been initialized: with 2 or 3? That's why these things aren't allowed

Answer (score 12):

This seems to be what you want:

```
public partial class TrackTyped : Component
{
    IContainer components = null;

    public TrackTyped()
        : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public TrackTyped(IContainer container)
        : this()
    {
        container.Add(this);
    }
}
```

The order of the statements in the second constructor is different now, though. If that matters, then there's not really a good way to do what you want, since even though you have the same *line*, the functionality is subtly different. In that case, you'll just have to have the single line repeated. Don't sweat it.

And you are reading the spec correctly: it does have to be one or the other.

Answer (score 8):

Usually done in a class having multiple properties to be initialized via constructor and some of them being optional.
We have a one biggest constructor which takes in **ALL** parameters which calls the base constructor. All other constructors redirect to this constructor by passing a null/default value to this big constructor. This way, all initialization code remains in a single place, reusable by others.

```
public MissingEntityException(Type type, string criteria, string message = "") 
    : this(type, criteria, message, null)
{           
}

public MissingEntityException(Type type, string criteria, string message, Exception innerException) 
     : base(message, innerException) 
{
    this.EntityType = type;
    this.Criteria = criteria;
}
```

This is supported across hierarchy and can involve any number or parameters.

Answer (score 2):

is this what you are looking for?

```
public partial class TrackTyped : Component
{
    IContainer components = null; 
    public TrackTyped() : base()
    {
        // logic for InitializeComponent() here
    } 

    public TrackTyped(IContainer container) : this()
    {
        container.Add(this)
    }
}
```

btw: that's an interesting usage for the second ctor:

```
var a = TrackTyped(container);
```

I wonder if deleting the second ctor and doing this is would be clearer for you?  (same end result)

```
container.Add(new TrackTyped());
```

Comment: you make a fine point, so i dug one level deeper and found that the reasoning was to make my component useable with Winforms designer, which will automatically add a line to the containing component's initialize routine like so: this.trackTypedTextComponent1 = new EomApp1.Components.TrackTyped(this.components);