# Can I call both this and base overloads in a constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, constructor-overloading

The closest thread I could find was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724133/how-do-i-call-both-constructor-initializers-base-and-this), but the scenario there is different - the base constructor to be called is the default one. Here I need to specify which parameter I want to pass it.

Say we have the following scenario:

```
    public class Base
    {
        public string Str;

        public Base(string s)
        {
            Str = s;
        }
    }

    public class A : Base
    {
        public string Str2;

        public A(string str2)
            : base(str2)
        {
            Str2 = str2;
        }

        public A(string str2, string str)
            : base(str)
        {
            Str2 = str2;
        }
    }
```

I want to avoid repeating the same logic in A's 2nd constructor overload (technically I could wrap all the logic into a function reducing the copy-paste / improving maintainability, for at the end all overloads would rely in the same code. Would follow this if there is no other solution).

I thought I could call first A's 1st constructor overload and afterwards the base one. But seems I can't.

What is the approach here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach would be

```
public class A : Base
{
    public string Str2;

    public A(string str2)
        : this(str2, str2)
    {
    }

    public A(string str2, string str)
        : base(str)
    {
        Str2 = str2;
    }
}
```

The single parameter constructor of `A` calls the 2 parameter constructor of `A` passing in the same string to both parameters using `this(` instead of `base(`. You then remove the body of the single parameter constructor because all of the work is being done in the two parameter constructor.